# installing play framework 2.4 on windows 7

Tags: java, playframework

some questions:

i unzipped the full offline distribution (400+ mb) to C:\Program Files\Play2.4

Unzipping created a directory "activator-dist-1.3.5" within which are bin, lib, repository, templates, etc.

i assume i put the contents of activator-dist-1.3.5 into C:\Program Files\Play2.4?

i setup an user environment variable name: PLAY_HOME, value: C:\Program Files\Play2.4 and then added ;%PLAY_HOME% to the end of the system variable "Path"

i've tried calling "play" from dos both with and without "activator-dist-1.3.5" directory and both return "play is not recognized as an internal or external command"

some other answers to this question mention the root play dir should have "play.bat" but all i see is "activator.bat"

i read readme.html and opened activator.bat, it launched a dos window, which promptly closed. 
http://localhost:8888/home goes nowhere.
For those who don't yet speak "play", what is Activator UI?

Answer (score 3):

Since play 2.3, the play command was replaced with the activator command. Take a look to [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights23).

If you put the folder activator-dist-1.3.5 into C:\Program Files\Play2.4 then your enviroment variable must be set to C:\Program Files\Play2.4\activator-dist-1.3.5\bin. You can also put that path directly into the PATH environment variable.

Activator UI is a web aplication that helps you create play applications. You can think of it as the graphical version of the activator command line tool. [Here](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/docs) is the documentation

Answer (score 2):

ok, here is what ive figured out:

1. the environment variable has to point to the bin directory (thx Victor)
2. from w/in dos window (the "console"), cd to the the root play dir (not bin) and type "activator" not "play"

all other documentation and stackoverflow answers refer to the pre 2.3 versions of play and will not help you.

then a bunch of stuff happens: online maven call (even though i downloaded the offline dist) and a bunch of calls to the play root dir/repository for jars.

of course localhost:9000 and localhost:8888 still get connection refused.
now if you manually open activator.bat in root play dir it launches another dos window, makes a network call (firewall allow) and opens a browser win to: http://127.0.0.1:8888/home which is some sort of "welcome to activator" screen with sample apps .. sort of like the tomcat mngt page.

i hope to only define and start/stop apps from w/in my IDE, so eventually i'll be looking for how to disable this default activator behavior

next up.. how to setup intelliJ:
i went here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE and defined an SBt task instead of a play task in run/debug configurations of my new project.
now project start makes maven calls for jars but then dies on:

[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=...repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.apache/apache/14/jars/apache.jar

stopping and restarting did a bunch more maven calls (really slow) but eventually "done updating" and localhost:9000/ now shows welcome screen :)

not completely painless but certainly simpler than a spring app

onEdit:

sorry play, but i've moved to spring boot because:

1. i create new projects by copying existing and making changes. its much faster than creating a new proj from scratch. Thus the activator thing (which does not work) is not useful to me and just represents a security prob (like apache web management screen) that need be disabled
2. no where is there a clear, concise and complete list of settings to get play running correctly in intelliJ (the 2nd most popular IDE avail)
3. asynchronous, non-blocking and micro services are not unique to play and spring (or others) can be made to work in a similar fashion
4. We have so many technologies to learn and it does'nt make sense to invest a lot of time mastering one with limited corporate buy in
5. i want to stop/start from w/in my IDE and not have to have a bunch of dos windows open. i know this is possible in play, but documentation makes it feel as though its not the preferred method
6. although i appreciate that the play directory structure is less flexible, its still not the command/controller/manager/dao/model world that is the most often seen for java apps

i investigated play because spring was getting to the point of having too many ways to configure too many things in too many places that were documented differently across versions. Also, large sub-projects in spring (like security) garnered their own books on the subject because they were so complex to figure out. At the end of the day, the level of security (for example) needed (or the manner in was implemented) went beyond what avail via simple configuration and after all the customization we were left wondering whether spring security just got in the way instead of providing real time saving and usefulness.
Spring boot hopes to help in that its an opinionated configuration where a collection of configuration basic best practices are encouraged/enforced.

and lets re real.. time saving on a slightly more concise language or a slightly different proj structure or dynamic class loading is not whats important.
The majority of time spent on projects, by far, is the time spent researching, thinking and investigating architectures, technologies, databases and presentation schemes.
I prob only spend 20% of my time coding and 80% trying to figure out the strategic vision needed to create software that has maximum usefulness and is "future friendly" (not needing to be re-coded every 3 years)

Answer (score 0):

trying to get working in IJ 14 ultimate:

jamesward.com has a tutorial and video, but its for older versions of IJ and play and only covers a small % of necc. configurations.

jetbrains has a tutorial but it also only covers play 2 and older IJ which does not translate to 14 and 2.4

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE helps, but just w/ setting up an SBT Task

all the other project settings are a mystery for example:

- project source need be defined to even show your project directories in proj tree
- facet setup add does not list scala as option
- why is scala lib pointing to users[me].ivy2\cache..? (i would think all necc libs are w/in play root\lib
- should i setup a global lib pointed to play\lib?
- run/debug config need env var pointed to PLAY_HOME?

basically all classes are not being resolved in IJ editor.
project structure lists 109 problems like:

Library SBT: joda-time:joda-time:2.3:jar is not used [Fix]

seems like i'm missing a global lib definition.
i'm able to get my app running, but i dont know how useful its going to be when the 2nd most popular IDE throws red bars at every import: "play."

Answer (score 0):

so far i've deleted my project and recreated about 10 times.. trying diff settings, still w/ no luck.

checking google play mailing group, i tried to create via activator ui.. but could not launch activator until i deleted the RUNNING_PID file in the play root dir

now i'm back at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/home to create a new app

at create new proj i get error: "cannot find project/build.properties".
lets try adding a blank build.properties where its expected.. nope, error: "destination already has files in it"

not that it really matters, sample templates have no knowledge of IDE and thus provide no insight into how to configure IJ. New\Import project does not list IJ as an option in choosing an external model

...whatever...

"Mr McKitrick.. after careful consideration ..."